# Openshift: redeploy source-to-image container with latest commit

Tags: openshift

I have a simple [source-to-image deployment](https://blog.openshift.com/create-s2i-builder-image/) in Openshift (some webpage with HTML and Javascript). The deployment was built from an Apache template, fetching code from a repository in GitLab.

Now there is a new release of the webpage at GitLab that must be deployed. I tried to redeploy, but Openshift fetches again the commit initially deployed, not the HEAD. How can I force Openshift to fetch the HEAD of the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to do a re-build, instead of a re-deploy. Only the re-build fetches the most recent source from the repository. One must go to ***Builds*** > ***Builds***, select the one corresponding to the deployment and then click on the ***Start Build*** button:

[image]

Comment: Or from the command line use ``oc start-build yourbuildconfigname``.